# How do I calculate mu and sigma?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and that 
${P(X \le 5) = 0.8}$ and $P(X\ge 0) = 0.6$
What are the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$

So far I've calculated $\frac{5-\mu}{ \sigma} = 0.84$
now I don't know where I would go from this point to calculate $\mu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

From $$P(X \geq 0 ) = 0.6$$

we have

$$P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \geq \frac{0-\mu}{\sigma} \right) = 0.6$$

You should be able to obtain another linear equation from above.

With two equations and two unknown, you should be able to solve for your $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Edit:

If you have $$\frac{5-\mu}{\sigma}=0.84$$ then we can write them as $$5=\mu+0.84\sigma\tag{1}$$

If we have $$\frac{0-\mu}{\sigma}=c$$

where $c$ is a known value.

then we have $$0=\mu+c\sigma\tag{2}$$

Hence, we just have to solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously for example by elimination or substitution.

Comment: So what would be the set up be for that ?

Comment: You have computed $\frac{5-\mu}{\sigma}=0.84$, you should be able to compute what is $\frac{0-\mu}{\sigma}$ too as well using the same trick.

Comment: Well i got 0.25 afterwards idk how to set up the equation

Comment: See edit to address how to set up a system of linear equations.

Comment: btw, $P(X \geq 0 ) =0.6$ means $P(X \leq 0) =0.4$.